# Feature file shows warning for every step even though I have created step definitions for all the steps

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I have imported all the required dependencies through maven for cucumber. But in my feature file whenever I specify the Scenario, it shows warning saying ***"Step xxxx does not have a matching glue code"***.
Even though when I run it, it executes all the the steps from step definition file.

I am using:
eclipse IDE : 4.12.0
Installed : Cucumber eclipse plugin : 0.0.23

Maven Dependencies:

> junit-jupiter-api : 5.5.2
>
> cucumber-java : 4.7.2
>
> cucumber-jvm-deps : 1.0.6
>
> cucumber-junit : 4.7.2
>
> selenium-java : 3.141.59
>
> cucumber-core : 4.7.2

Below are the images of my feature file, step definitions file, testRunner and project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Even if I press F3 it does not display the step definition.

Comment: This sounds similar to troubles I've had with Visual Studio and their implementation of cucumber called SpecFlow. I had to delete some temporary cache files that mapped steps to methods. I'm sure Eclipse does something similar, where it saves these step mappings in a cached file on your computer. I don't use Eclipse, but trying to delete those cache files created by the IDE might help. And please for future reference [please do not post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3092298). Post the actual code instead and format it in the question editor.